# User getting unexpected error while accessing SharePoint Site

Tags: sharepoint-server, error, web, page-not-found

We have one user getting unexpected error while accessing SharePoint Site.

User can access any other sites in that web application with no issue.

I did fiddler trace and it shows that browser (any) request for favicon and it can't find it. The site is `http://intranet/sites/teamB` and browser requesting the favicon under root site (`/favicon.ico`). Since it's not there returns error 404.

I asked the user to navigate the favicon url (`http://intranet/sites/teamB/_layouts/15/images/favicon.ico`) directly and he gets error 404 which works fine for rest of users.

Here is Fiddler trace. Please let me know what is going on. Also if he uses different computer it works fine.

```
Result  Protocol    Host    URL Body    Caching Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom
232 200 HTTP    intranet    /_layouts/sp.js?rev=SpGB4%2FzYmCWpwoPWNG2dsg%3D%3D  72,868  max-age=31536000    application/x-javascript    iexplore:4956   [#232]
233 401 HTTP    intranet    /sites/teamB/sitepages/home.aspx    0   iexplore:4956   [#233]
234 200 HTTP    intranet    /sites/teamB/sitepages/home.aspx    429 private text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:4956   [#234]
235 404 HTTP    intranet    /favicon.ico    0   iexplore:4956   [#235]
238 401 HTTP    intranet    /sites/teamB/sitepages/home.aspx    0   chrome:6540 [#238]
239 401 HTTP    intranet    /sites/teamB/sitepages/home.aspx    0   chrome:6540 [#239]
240 200 HTTP    intranet    /sites/teamB/sitepages/home.aspx    429 private text/html; charset=utf-8    chrome:6540 [#240]
241 404 HTTP    intranet    /favicon.ico    0   chrome:6540 [#241]
```

Comment: is favicon image is still in the images folder under 15 hive? all users from that site collection getting the same error? what about the site colelction admin?

Comment: all other users are fine. if same user use different computer it works fine. he only has issue with this site on his laptop. I removed his permission and re-added back but no help. yes the favicon still is under 15 hive. All other users have no issue accessing site.

Comment: then it is his laptop issue, try with different browser i.e chrome, firefox...also clear the browser cache, reset it and then try

Comment: already tired that with chrome, IE and firefox. removed cache. flushed dns. all that already tried. could not find anything in ULS and IIS log neither.

Comment: are you using the kerbros?

Comment: just add one thing i missed to mention. He is on VPN and accessing our intranet site. He can access any other intranet sites fine but except this one. For example he can access http://intranet/sites/teamA with not problem but he can't access http://intranet/sites/teamB.

Comment: no we use NTLM authentication.

Comment: tryt o add site into trust zone of browser//

Comment: i tried that as well.

Comment: that is really weird, only one site collection and for one person....is their any proxy settings for browser? also are you accessing the FQDN? i am totally loss why one person having the issue.

Comment: it's extremely weird and i agree with you. I already tired the FQDN and there are no proxy. the strange part is that only happens to one site.

Comment: what permission level user has, may be increase that level and see if that fix.....but it is not actual fix...

Comment: the issue was with incorrect host file entry. Our networking team added entry in his host file which was pointing to old environment.

Answer (score 1):

the issue was with incorrect host file entry. Our networking team added entry in his host file which was pointing to old environment.